# How do I get the best result with images in UIButton and UITableViewCell for both iPhone and iPhone 4 retina?

Tags: iphone

Do I simply check for screen size and use twice the resolution for the iPhone 4, or do I need to tell the UIButton/UITableViewCell to render the image in high resolution?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're setting the image in Interface Builder or loading it using `+[UIImage imageNamed:]`, simply add a double resolution image to your project with a "@2x" suffix. (For example `myimage.png` would be `myimage@2x.png`.) The OS will take care of the rest for you.

See [Updating Your Image Resource Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10-SW8) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you include a high-resolution version of the image with the same name, **but with `@2x` before the extension**, iOS will automatically choose the correct resolution according to display resolution, as long as you use the `[UIImage imageNamed:]` function, or set the image in IB.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1